# Split string with dates into three substrings

Tags: python, regex

I have strings of the following format: "Description of stuffI\n1 31 2019\nPlace of business"

For this string, the code below works perfectly.The problem comes in when there is a digit in the first group, such as

"Description of 2nd stuffI\n1 31 2019\nPlace of business"

or

"1)Description of stuffI\n1 31 2019\nPlace of business"

How do I allow a digit in the first group without messing with the date capture that comes later?

```
pattern = r"(\D*)(\d.*\d.*\d)\D(.*)$"

example_string = "Description of stuffI\n1 31 2019\nPlace of business"

match = re.match(pattern, example_string)

if match:
    print("Group 1:", match.group(1).strip())
    print("Group 2:", match.group(2).strip())
    print("Group 3:", match.group(3).strip())
else:
    print("No match found!")
```

Comment: You probably can just use `re.search(r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2} \d{1,2} \d{4}(?!\d)', example_string)` or something similar (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jrKOC0/1)).

Comment: If you know there are newlines include them as hard patterns and match everything in the first and third group no matter the content?

Comment: Why not just str.split() on '\n' ?

Answer (score -1):

This works:

The first part of the date can be a month or day of month. In the middle would be either the day of the month or a month itself. The last part is a year with two or four digits.

```
example_string = "1)Description of 2nd studddffI\n01 12 2019\nPlace of business"

regex = re.compile(r"(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[ ./-](0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[ ./-](\d{2}|\d{4})\D")


# Search for a date pattern in the string
date_match = re.search(regex, example_string)

if date_match:
    start, end = date_match.span()
    part1 = example_string[:start].strip()
    date = example_string[start:end].strip()
    part3 = example_string[end:].strip()

    print("Part 1:", part1)
    print("Date:", date)
    print("Part 3:", part3)
else:
    print("No date match found!")
```

Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew and AmigoJack

Comment: There is no reason to use `.` if you **don't** want _any_ character, and there is no reason to use `*` if you **don't** want _any_ repitition, as in your original code. This equals to very vague descriptions like "_over there_" - why not making it more precise to begin with? Furthermore if it's a date you can narrow it down to legal allowed ranges, like `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` for the day. Your current solution will also allow several other separators, since `[ -/]` is a range from ASCII 0x20 to 0x2F instead of only these 3 characters - better put the minus to the end like `[./ -]`.